# Trying to open new Window from pageBlockTable; replaces current page or new tab instead

Tags: javascript, chrome

We have a custom Service console that uses a pageBlockTable to display the recent Cases for a selected Contact.  I would like to use the Case.id from each row to open a new window, as there is information in the current Console that is easier to reference w/o having to switch Tabs all the time (vs. alt+tab, or controlling the position of the new window.

I have a button in an iFrame that works as intended to open a new Window; from the Case list^, though, the selected Case either replaces the current page (href version, below) or opens a new tab (outputLink version).

In the example below, I commented out the outputLink (which opens in a new tab) for the time being.  The button replaces the existing page, which is less useful.

```
   <apex:column width="100px" headerValue="{!$ObjectType.case.fields.casenumber.label}">
             <!-- apex:outputLink value="/{!historyItem.id}" onclick="openCaseHistory(); return false;" target="_blank" >
                     <apex:param name="isdtp" value="lt" />
                     {!historyItem.casenumber}
            </apex:outputLink -->
            <!-- button version -->                                           
            <a href="/{!historyItem.id}" class="btn" style="text-decoration:none" 
                                        onclick="window.open(this.href, 'caseWin', height=750,width=1400,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); return false;">
                    {!historyItem.casenumber}
            </a>
       </apex:column>
       <script>
                function openCaseHistory() {
                    console.log('https://cs15.salesforce.com/{!historyItem.id}?isdtp=vw');
                    var historyWindow = window.open('/{!historyItem.id}/e?retURL=%2F{!selectedContact}&isdtp=lt',
                        '_blank',
                        config='height=750,width=1400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,status=no');                            
            }                                                                   
    </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't tell browser whether it should open link in new browser tab or new browser window. It is up to user to define this behaviour in browser settings.

Comment: Which would make sense, yet on the same page, an apex:commandButton can call a similar method and it will open a separate window?  If so, so be it; it just seems arbitrary.